# How to read config file values in ashx page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config, ashx

I am making an application. In that application I added one ashx handler. Here I want to read some values from config file but I am not getting how to read values. I am using code as

```
 public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    { 
        public bool IsReusable 
        { 
            get { return false; } 
        } 


        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
        { 
           //Here i want to read config values.
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class can be used from anywhere. You have to add reference to `System.Configuration.dll`, if you have not already did it.

To read a config value

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
        { 
             var cfgValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cfgKey"];
        }
```